# Tableview text input fields nil during submission if not in view

Tags: ios, swift, forms, tableview

I'm creating a form using a UITableview with labels on the left, and text inputs, and true/false selectors on the right. There is a button at the top to validate the data, and save it.  However I found a bug, if the phone is in landscape mode and one of the fields is out of view during submission, the field not displayed crashes the app as the value of that cell is nil.

My code for the "Submit" button:

```swift
let cell0 = tableView.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)) as! CellString
let cell1 = tableView.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row: 1, section: 0)) as! CellString
let cell2 = tableView.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row: 2, section: 0)) as! MoreInfoUITableViewCell
let cell3 = tableView.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row: 3, section: 0)) as! CellString
let cell4 = tableView.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row: 4, section: 0)) as! CellString
let cell5 = tableView.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row: 5, section: 0)) as! MoreInfoUITableViewCell
let cell6 = tableView.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row: 6, section: 0)) as! MoreInfoUITableViewCell
let cell7 = tableView.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row: 7, section: 0)) as! CellBool
let cell8 = tableView.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row: 8, section: 0)) as! CellBool
let cell9 = tableView.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row: 9, section: 0)) as! CellBool
```

Code to add the fields to the new object:

```swift
let newObject = Aircraft(context: context)
newAircraft.obj0 = cell0.textInput.text!
newAircraft.obj1 = cell1.textInput.text
newAircraft.obj2 = cell2.rightLabel.text
newAircraft.obj3 = cell3.textInput.text
newAircraft.obj4 = cell4.textInput.text
newAircraft.obj5 = cell5.rightLabel.text
newAircraft.obj6 = cell6.rightLabel.text
newAircraft.obj7 = cell7.trueFalseSelector.isOn
newAircraft.obj8 = cell8.trueFalseSelector.isOn
newAircraft.obj9 = cell9.trueFalseSelector.isOn
```

Comment: Your tableview is not your data model. The tableview simply displays data. If the user changes the data in the cell you must update your data model. You then validate the data in your model, not in the view

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you must understand that `cellForRow(at:)` will only return a cell if the tableview currently has a visible cell for that row. It will not call your table view's data source method to obtain a cell if there is no visible cell, it will return nil.

If you want to get data from each cell I would suggest implementing events for textfield changes in each cell like this:

```
protocol MyCellDelegate {
    func onTextChange(text: String, index: Int)
}

class MyCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var field: UITextField!
    var delegate: MyCellDelegate?

    override func awakeFromNib() {
            field.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textFieldDidChange(_:)), for: .editingChanged)
    }
        
        
    @objc func textFieldDidChange(_ textField: UITextField) {
            delegate?.onTextChange(text: textField.text!, index: index) //index = cell's row index

    }
}
```

When text is changed in the cell, delegate should propagate the change to the viewController which would save the value in an instance variable.

In Parent View Controller, confirm the `MyCellDelegate`

```
extension ... {
   func onTextChange(text: String, index: Int) {
     // save the text to the variable according to index
   }
}
```

Then, when you press on the button, you would simply take values from instance variables.